# Merging results in a row depending on another field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, merge

Below is the source table and the output I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I would like each another_table.id to only appear once in the output, with subsequent values displaying in new columns

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you want to have?

Comment: are you trying take the data from table 1 so that you have one row per another_table.id?

Comment: @Cristian how can i do this? i'm not good at sql.. :(

Comment: @LinkinTED (Example field 1 is my "status" (variable_id = 1 inicial status, variable_id=2 -> final status) and if i have a field 2 value in it i have to wrote the both in screen, so sorry cant explain it better, its so new to me..)

Comment: @MarkD nope, my table "another_table" is kinda "a details table" and it could be N rows to 1 relationship

Comment: I see that, I am just getting clarification that on your output you only want that details table to be shown once, with each of it's many outputs on the same row

Comment: Can you setup a small data set in SQLfiddle?

Comment: @MarkD thats exactly what i want

Comment: Anyone? Please i really need to do this :\

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output, given the table in your question. With CTEs instead of subqueries for added clarity...

```
with intials as(
SELECT id, 
another_table.id as another_table_id,
value as field_1
FROM
main_table
WHEN
variable.id = 1),

finals as(
SELECT id, 
another_table.id as another_table_id,
value as field_1
FROM
main_table
WHEN
variable.id = 2)

SELECT
initials.id,
initials.another_table_id
initials.value field_1,
finals.value field_2
FROM
initials
LEFT OUTER JOIN
finals on initials.another_table_id = finals.another_table_id;
```